# C++ printing a string in reverse

Tags: c++, string, pointers, reverse

This program works and does what is required. My question is in regards to the ReverseName function, and how it works exactly. I was able to reverse engineer it from some examples in my book, but I cant quite figure out how it works. I get Name is sent to it. i just dont understand how it is printed in reverse.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


void ReverseName(char *s ); 

int main(void){ 

    char Name[] ="John Doe";

    cout << "Name is: " << Name << "\n" << "Name Backwards is: " ;

    ReverseName(Name); 

    cout << "\nName is: "<< Name << '\n';

    return 0; 
} 

void ReverseName(char * s){ 

    if(*s){ 
        ReverseName(s+1); 
        cout << *s; 
        } 

    return; 
}
```

Comment: Follow the flow of execution (perhaps with a debugger).

Comment: and to add to @chris you can read on recursive functions

Comment: Use the debugger to set a break-point inside the function and then watch the variables as the function is recursively-called (by stepping through the execution).

Answer (score 2):

```
void ReverseName(char * s){ 

    if(*s){ 
        ReverseName(s+1); // come into the end of the string 
        cout << *s; 
        } 

    return; 
}
```

it just like this:

```
'J'
call --> 'o'
         call  ---> 'h'
                    call  ---> ...
                               call  ---> 'e'    (Recursion to the end)
```

and when the stack come to the end of recursion, it will execute back in order. then it just like.

```
                                       cout << 'e'
                            cout << ...
                 cout << 'h'
        cout << 'o'
cout << 'J' 

(come back from the call stack)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a recursive function.

It gets a pointer to a char array and calls itself until the the end of char array is reached, then it "unwinds" the recursion, printing all the chars from the back.

Answer (score 0):

ReverseName() is a recursive function.

http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/710-recursion/